# If I install the Loki beta, will I be able to upgrade to the official release?

Tags: system-installation, release-loki, updates

I'd like to install the Loki beta. When Loki is officially released, will I have to reinstall it? Or can I just upgrade it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to reinstall. There will be no upgrade path from the beta to the stable release.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, as far I know (unless I'm missing something), if you keep upgrading (apt upgrade) you will end up in stable when they push those changes.

Comment: @sojin While you will have all the packages, you will probably miss some config changes pushed on stable that are not in beta so some things might not look/work properly. Dirty upgrades are usually possible but not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall

Because config might be slightly different. Also the beta uses other sources than the stable release.